# How do I control a motor wirelessly?

Tags: embedded, wireless

I am a ME undergrad and am designing an implant device that requires programming knowledge. I honestly have no idea how to get started and am looking for advice. Basically what I need is a way to control a stepper motor. Stepper motor's use steps (pulses) to rotate the gear head. Now this motor I'm using needs 20 steps to revolve once. I need to be able to control the # of steps I want in a day per say. The motor I'm purchasing comes with an encoder which I'm guessing connects to the circuit board. Now what I want to do is have an external control (like a remote control for a toy)that can set these rates. I don't know anything about radio transmitters, or how to program the circuit board to do this for me. Any help would be appreciated, or books I can look into, websites, or tutorials. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, sounds like a challenging albeit interesting project.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of solving this problem, but it is more of a systems engineering question than a programming question; until you know what the system looks like, there is no way of determining what parts will be implemented in software.  More details would be required to provide a specific answer.

For example what are the security/safety considerations?

What wireless technology do you need to use? e.g. RF or IR, if RF then licensing may be an issue, and that may vary from country to country.  You could use BlueTooth, ZigBee, or even WiFi, but these technologies are probably more expensive and complex than necessary for such a simple application.  If IR then is immunity from interference from TV remotes or PC IrDA ports or similar required?

If the commands/signals from the remote are complex you will probably need both the remote and the motor driver to incorporate a micro-controller and software.  On the other hand if you just need increase/decrease functions then it would be entirely possible to implement the remote functionality you describe without any processing at all (depending on teh communication technology you choose).

What is the motor encoder for?  Stepper motors do not normally need an encoder since the controller can simply count steps executed in either direction to determine position.  Is the encoder incremental or absolute?  If it is incremental, then it is certainly not needed; if it is absolute than it may be useful if you need to know the exact position of the motor on power-up without having to perform an initialisation or requiring end-stop switches.

You mentioned a "circuit board"; what hardware do you already have?  What does it do?  Do you have documentation for it?  If it is commercially available, can you provide a link so we can see the documentation?

As you can see you have more system-level design issues to solve before you even consider software implementation, so the question is not yet ready to be answered here on SO.  I suggest you seek out your university's EE department and team-up with someone with electronics expertise do design a complete system, then consider the software aspects.

Comment: Actually, using a Bluetooth or ZigBee RS-232 cable replacement would no doubt be the easiest and cheapest solution. Just buy some from any electronic's store and smack 'em to your UART on the microcontroller. To buy some junky wideband toy remote and try to decode whatever rubbish signal it outputs using a RF chip on the same frequency is a *very* complex project.

Comment: @Lundin: When I suggested ZigBee et al, I said *complex* not *difficult*; they are not synonymous.  It would be a lot of circuitry and processing (even if you do not have to implement it yourself) to perform a very simple task, and that may be prohibitive for a high-volume, low-cost product, but OK for a one-off.

Comment: Cable replacement is just something sitting on a DB9 d-sub connector and everything is pre-configured. Though of course if you buy a Bluetooth or Zigbee SMD module and put it on a circuit board, there will be a bit more configuration stuff involved.

Comment: @Lundin: I know what it is.  You entirely missed my point, a systems *complexity* is not a measure of how difficult it is to put together. You might use a standard PC to control this motor, and that would involve several tens of millions of logic gates and lines of code; highly complex, but anyone with a PC might be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well worth taking a look at the Microchip site:

http://www.microchip.com/forums/f170.aspx

They produce microcontrollers that can be programmed to do exactly what you require (and a lot more).